# Indesign: How to preserve overrides when changing a paragraph style

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, style

Many a times, I assigned different text to one paragraph style, but with different overrides. So, they look different though having a same paragraph style. Later on, I want to give each different-looking text a unique paragraph style.

But when I duplicate a paragraph style and assign it to one of those text boxes, the overrides are gone. I want to keep those overrides, so I can redefine the newly-created paragraph style from those overrides.

The question is, how to preserve overrides when assigning text to a new paragraph style?

I'm using InDesign v14.0.3 x64 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you probably make the error of duplicating your style *without having the new styling selected*.

To create a new paragraph style from a paragraph style with overrides do like this:

- Select a paragraph which has the overrides you want to turn into a new paragraph style (or just place the cursor within the paragraph).
- In the *Paragraph Styles* panel, click the *Create new style* button.
- Select the newly created style to apply it to the selected paragraph.

Now you have a new paragraph style with the wanted appearance and no overrides.

[image]